# ONNX extracting sub-models from onnx model [error]

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, onnx

I'm trying to divide the onnx model into sub-models using **extract_model** found in [Extracting Sub-model with Inputs Outputs Tensor Names](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/PythonAPIOverview.md#extracting-sub-model-with-inputs-outputs-tensor-names).
I'm applying the extraction on **squeezenet1.1-7.onnx** found in [onnx models](https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/main/vision/classification/squeezenet/model) :

```
model_path = 'squeezenet.onnx'
onnx_model = onnx.load(model_path)
onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)
input_path = model_path
output_path = "path/to/save/the/extracted/model.onnx" # I inserted the corresponding path.
input_names = ["data"]
output_names = ["squeezenet0_conv10_fwd"]
onnx.utils.extract_model(input_path, output_path, input_names, output_names)
```

I am getting the error below (maybe I didn't understand well how to use **extract_model**) :

```
---> 17 onnx.utils.extract_model(input_path, output_path, input_names, output_names)
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/onnx/checker.py in check_model(model, full_check)
     95     # If model is a path instead of ModelProto
     96     if isinstance(model, str):
---> 97         C.check_model_path(model)
     98         if full_check:
     99             onnx.shape_inference.infer_shapes_path(model, check_type=True, strict_mode=True)
ValidationError: squeezenet0_conv0_weight in initializer but not in graph input
```

Appreciate any kind of help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because onnx cannot find a node with the name 'squeezenet0_conv0_weight'

1. Open your onnx model in Netron and take a look at NN structure. Netron is a nice program to analyze a NN.
2. Left click on a node
3. A node will have properties like ATTRIBUTES, INPUTS, OUTPUTS. It is strange, but often nodes can be uniquely identified only by the output name. I mean by names in section OUTPUTS field: output:,
   not by a name in section NODE PROPERTIES field: name